Create a dendrogram with customized text and colored
I have the shiny app below in which I want to create a dendrogram or hierarchy plot like the image below. First based on Header Name and then based on Sub header 1. I use box() but Im not sure that will work cause I do not know how could I connect them via arrows. Maybe I can use another package for dendrogramms but Im not sure if I can put the counts and percentages like in my image. Its not necessary to have boxes but the color and text are important
library(shiny)
library(shinydashboard)
d2<-structure(list(`Header Name` = c("Trodelvy LOT received first", 
                                     "Trodelvy LOT received first", "Trodelvy LOT received first", 
                                     "EV LOT received first", "EV LOT received first", "EV LOT received first", 
                                     "Trodelvy LOT received first", "Trodelvy LOT received first", 
                                     "Trodelvy LOT received first", "EV LOT received first", "EV LOT received first", 
                                     "EV LOT received first", "Trodelvy LOT received first", "Trodelvy LOT received first", 
                                     "Trodelvy LOT received first", "EV LOT received first", "EV LOT received first", 
                                     "EV LOT received first", "Trodelvy LOT received first", "Trodelvy LOT received first", 
                                     "Trodelvy LOT received first", "EV LOT received first", "EV LOT received first", 
                                     "EV LOT received first"), `Sub Header 1` = c(NA, "EV after Trodelvy", 
                                                                                  "No EV after Trodelvy", NA, "Trodelvy after EV", "Trodelvy after EV", 
                                                                                  NA, "EV after Trodelvy", "No EV after Trodelvy", NA, "Trodelvy after EV", 
                                                                                  "Trodelvy after EV", NA, "EV after Trodelvy", "No EV after Trodelvy", 
                                                                                  NA, "Trodelvy after EV", "Trodelvy after EV", NA, "EV after Trodelvy", 
                                                                                  "No EV after Trodelvy", NA, "Trodelvy after EV", "Trodelvy after EV"
                                     )), row.names = c(NA, -24L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"
                                     ))

header_counts <- d2 %>%
  group_by(`Header Name`) %>%
  summarise(Count = n())

# Define UI
ui <- dashboardPage(
  dashboardHeader(title = "Basic Shiny Dashboard"),
  dashboardSidebar(),
  dashboardBody(
    
    fluidRow(
      box(title = "", paste("Bladder",nrow(d2)),width = 2,solidHeader = T)
    )
  )
)

# Define server logic
server <- function(input, output) {
  
}

# Run the application 
shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)



I suggest you look at dendextend. And maybe also shinyheatmaply
